find : unknow predicate - filesname
this is my script :
find */*/*20* -maxdepth 1 -type f -mmin +$((730 * 1440)) -not -path 'stockdress/*' -not -path 'oldstockdress/*' > temp.txt

I am getting this error while i'am running this command:

find: unknown predicate `- lolodress/2023-09-23_referencenumber.txt

How can I handle directory names that start with a dash and space when using the find command to avoid the "find: unknown predicate" error?
i tried :
find */*/*20* -maxdepth 1 -type f -mmin +$((730 * 1440)) -not -path 'stockdress/*' -not -path 'oldstockdress/*' -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "temp.txt"' {} \; 

but i am still having the same error.
i want the find command to search for all filesname whith the name 20 in and sent the output as a newline for each filesname found to the tmp.txt files.

Change */*/*20* to ./*/*/*20*; the leading ./ will ensure that even a directory with a - starting its name isn't confused for an action.

That said, you should probably investigate why the directory has a name like this. I doubt it's intended.

BTW, if you want to ignore the directory stockdress and the directory oldstockdress, it's much more efficient to put -name stockdress -prune -o -name oldstockdress -prune -o at the beginning of your predicate set (right after -maxdepth 1, rather, since -maxdepth is a global setting; before the -type f); pruning them means that find doesn't even traverse them, whereas -not -path does the work of looking inside those directories and then throws away the results.

Are you using Gnu find? Then read in the man-page for find the second (a bit lengthy) paragraph of the OPTIONS section. find is, by its nature, a bit different from the usual Unix/Linux utilities, when it comes to filenames starting with a dash.
